# slow boot after nvidia drivers installation

Tags: boot

I upgraded my ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 to 20.04 recently. While it was upgrading to 20.04, I saw an error related to nvidia drivers. after the upgrade finished, I had to manually reboot my system but apart from that, everything seemed fine. The next time I powered on my Laptop, I saw a black screen, so I went to recovery mode-> fix broken packages -> hit reboot. but I felt like my laptop was taking a lot of time to boot.
During this time, my nvidia driver was 340.108
On nvidia site, it recommended me version 390.147. So I did `apt search nvidia-driver` and then `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`
Nothing changed except when I do `modinfo nvidia`, it says `version : 390.147`
The black screen appears every time, then it loads but takes a lot of time to boot.

I am using nvidia GeForce 820M on a dual-boot system with windows 8.1 and  ubuntu 20.04, system has 4 GB RAM. I know it's not a fast hardware but it never seemed this slow before. I feel like I have made a huge blunder with my nvidia drivers.

output of `systemd-analyze` =
`Startup finished in 3.763s (kernel) + 1min 45.317s (userspace) = 1min 49.081s  graphical.target reached after 1min 45.274s in userspace`

I am a newbie in Ubuntu, please explain in layman language.
Also this is my first question so please ignore any mistakes I might have made.
I'll provide any required information in comments if asked.
Much Thanks.

Comment: 16.04 to 20.04 is a big jump.  I presume a slower boot is possible.  I mean, presumably, this computer isn't new (since it was using 16.04).  I don't think we can expect a computer to run as fast as it did with an older version of the OS since more packages would have been added to it.  How is the system after you log in?  Is it slower?  Do you plan to go up to 22.04?

Comment: Plus during the successive online release upgrades may have unpredictable quirks. Considering the huge differences between 16.04 and 18.04 or newer such upgrade shouldn't have been done, period. The obvious suggestion is do your backups and install fresh. Always prefer newer which in this case is 22.04.

Comment: @Ray Yes, I bought this laptop in 2014, and yes, it does freeze sometimes even after I login. Do you think I didn't mess up my nvidia drivers by installing two different versions twice? once by GUI ( 340.108 ) and the other from terminal ( 390.147 ) Thanks for responding.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have a lot of coding related stuff on this system, can not afford to do a fresh install because then it would take a lot of days to just get all my projects up and running. Although I appreciate your quick answer, is there any way I can check whether or not my nvidia drivers are messed up?

Comment: You can uninstall all NVidia drivers if you think the NVidia drivers is the cause.  Then go up to 22.04 and then pick one NVidia driver to install.  I don't think installing two alone would be the cause; if there was a conflict, I guess it wouldn't be slow.  Instead, it would crash, no?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Wow...kind words!  see it was my decision to take a break from programming. And I don't need you to tell me I had enough time to do this or that. If you don't want to answer the question in a polite manner, then don't bother answering at all.

Comment: @Ray Yeah that makes sense. Thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome!  For what it's worth...I tend to use the drivers from NVidia's web site.  Not officially part of Ubuntu yet, but I've rarely gone wrong with the latest NVIdia driver.  In any case, pick one and stick with that one; if it doesn't work, ask a question here.  Don't install one and then install a second next time, and then ask for help -- things should work with the latest one, even if your system is a bit old.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I had the nvidea graphic card installed properly for only a couple of days, then I was proposed an automatic upgdate. this update included a lot of nvidea package.

After installing and rebooting, I had a black screen but also ubuntu would take at least 2 min before presenting me witht the login prompt.

I ended up switching back to the "nouveau xorg" driver, rebooting, then purging all nvidea drivers. and reinstalling the nvidea driver by going to "additional drivers" in ubuntu panel and selecting the last one.

> apt remove --purge nvidia-*
>
> apt autoremove --purge
>
> apt clean